# Progress bar for uploading log with php

Tags: java, html, jquery, progress-bar

I am looking for a way to have a progress bar working with concurrent files being uploaded.

As of right now I use shell_exec to show a CLI of this progress from a log. This in turn is just running in a docker container which then would refresh every 25 seconds.

I want to improve on this and move forward. Before I do that am I going in the wrong direction with shell_exec I believe I am and that it can't be done this way.

Many thanks